# Negating "$\forall x\in\Bbb{R}^+$, if $x^2>4$, then $x>2$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm in my first discrete math class and am wondering about finding the negation for this statement:
$$\forall x\in\Bbb{R}^+, \text{if}\; x^2>4, \text{then}\; x>2$$
I understand that the initial statement is false so that would mean that the negation is true. I also have all the way up to
$$\exists x \in \Bbb{R}^+:$$
and I know that I need to change the "then" to "and", but I just don't know if I need to negate the inequality symbols or not. Either way, the negation comes out to be true so it satisfies that premise.

Comment: The initial statement is true...why do you say it is false?  I am assuming that $\mathbb R^+$ denotes the positive reals.

Comment: Now that I look at it more I see that it is true, no idea why I though it was false, thanks!
I also found the correct answer due to another community member linking me to a question that answered my question.

Comment: No worries.  Are you clear on the statement of the negation?  Just in words, to negate a statement like this, consider how you would disprove it.  You'd want to find a positive real number $x$ such that...   For instance, how would you disprove the (false) claim that you could extend the given statement to all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I could disprove the false claim that extending the given statement to all reals because if x<-2 then x^2>4 but x<2. And I found the answer is \existsx\inr^+:x^2>4 and x\leq2

Comment: Yes, that's right (though hard to read).

Comment: Yep, for sake of clarity for future readers, I reproduce the answer here:  $\exists x\in\mathbb R^+\mid x^2>4\text{ and }x\le 2$ which is $\exists x\mid a\land \lnot b\ $ negation of $\ \forall x,\ a\implies b$

Comment: I had a page pulled up that told me how to write in symbols on this site, but I can't find it anymore. Do you happen to have a link to that page so that I can bookmark it for future use?

Comment: Here it is : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, that page is now bookmarked so I will be writing more legibly in the future!